# .NET 5 performance issue while iterating a list

Tags: c#, .net-5, .net-4.8

I have two projects with different source code: one working with .NET 4.8 and the other with .NET 5. The only difference between them is the framework.

The same code block works much slower in .NET 5 than in .NET 4.8; there is about a 20-fold difference between them. I have read many sources, tried different codes, but could not reach better performance parity.

Here is my code:

```
public static List<Foo> GetColumnWithDataType(Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SmoColumnCollection columns)
{
    List<Foo> res = new List<Foo>();
    for (int i = 0; i < columns.Count; i++)
    {
        var result = DoSomeStaff(columns[i]);
        res.Add(result);
    }
    return res;
}

public static Foo DoSomeStaff(Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Column column) {

    var result = new Foo();

    if (column.SqlDataType == something)
        result.DataType = "1";
    else if (column.SqlDataType == something2)
        result.DataType = "2";
    .
    .
    .
    else
        result.DataType="0";
    return result;

}
public class Foo
{
    public string DataType { get; set; }
}
```

What am I missing in .NET 5 here?

Comment: Don't you know the data type of the column? This seems to be pretty expensive in process in order to don't map every column.

Comment: @LeandroBardelli I don't know the data type. I have to map it. But this is not the point. It works so fast with .net 4.8

Comment: One of the first step in any performance regression scenario should be to **profile**  to find what it is that is actually slower. I would assume that it is not actually iterating a list that is slow, but rather something to do with the database.

Comment: As JonasH said, for me the problem is not the list, is the work that you are doing for datatype. Anyway, you are asking for the reason of the slow, or you are asking to improve the performance?

Comment: In any case doesn't seems to be pretty logic that you don't know the columns of your database or what kind of information do you save, work, or show.

Comment: SMO is typically a performance problem incarnate no matter the framework, and a black box with regards to knowing what's slow and what's fast. It's conceivable the .NET 5 version is relying on an earlier port, or else on a path that happens to not be optimized in Core. I've burned myself on it enough now that my go-to for tasks like these is not SMO, if it can also be done with some simple queries on the system views and Dapper, or something more advanced like database projects.

Comment: The slowest step is adding return value from DoSomeStaff to the "res" object.

Comment: You can do `List<Foo> res = new List<Foo>(columns.Count);` and pre-allocate the list - might help a bit with speed.

Comment: Why do you return a "var" for a "Foo" type for only return DataType, that is indeed a string?

Answer (score 0):

```
public static string DoSomeStaff(Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Column column) {

    string result;

    if (column.SqlDataType == something)
        return "1";
    else if (column.SqlDataType == something2)
        return "2";
    .
    .
    .
    else
       return "0";
}
```

and using:

```
public static List<Foo> GetColumnWithDataType(Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SmoColumnCollection columns)
{
    List<Foo> res = new List<Foo>();
    for (int i = 0; i < columns.Count; i++)
    {

        res.Add(new Foo() { Datatype = DoSomeStaff(columns[i])});
    }
    return res;
}
```

Comment: Some explanation of this code is warranted.

Comment: What I try to do is simplify the dynamics and objects on memory, in any case I though the problem is the algorithm in general, because this work is disposed on each iteration.